# Merge objects to obtain a unique json object in MVC 4

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization

I'm trying to serialize an object in a different way that the default serialization does.
I have a list of objects like this:

```
public class PausesByAgentModel
{
    public PausesByAgentModel()
    {
        this.Pauses = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    [DisplayName( "Agent" )]
    public string AgentFullName { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Pauses { get; set; }
}
```

This object contains the different pauses for a Agent an the time for each pause in a dictionary because the pauses reasons are are dynamics (Key: Pause name, Value: Time in string format).
If I serialize this object as JsonResult to return it in my controller method, I get the following json:

```
{ 
    "data" : [
    { 
        "AgentFullName" : "John Doe", 
        [
            { "Break": "00:15:31" }, 
            { "Launch" : "01:01:23" }, 
            { "Mail" : "00:05:12" }
        ]
    } ] 
}
```

But I need that the pauses were placed like properties of the same object like this one:

```
{ 
    "data" : [
    { 
        "AgentFullName" : "John Doe", 
        "Break": "00:15:31", 
        "Launch" : "01:01:23", 
        "Mail" : "00:05:12"
    } ] 
}
```

I can't change the class design. So, I need to serialize the object in a different way as default design.

There is a way to merge or serialize the object like the second example?
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest create a anonymous type of PausesByAgentModel and json serialise that.

Answer (score 0):

As @qamar says on the comments, use a dynamic type.

```
public List<dynamic> ParseData(PausesByAgentModel model){
    List<dynamic> result = new List<dynamic>();

    foreach(String key in model.Keys){
        result.Add(new { pauses = key,value = model[key] });
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @BlaShadow, but doing this, the final result is an array of pauses and I need to get one object with all pauses as properties (and AgentFullName as proerty too). I should to add properties (AgentFullName and pauses) to an object instead objects to a List.